# imagejpeg creating black image

Tags: php, imagejpeg

I know it is an old question but I am not able to solve it. Here is my code

```
function add_ZK_mark($inputfile, $outputfile) {
$im = @imagecreatefromjpeg($inputfile);
$bg = @imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$textcolor = @imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 255);

list($x, $y, $type) = getimagesize($inputfile);
@imagejpeg($im, $outputfile);
@imagedestroy($im);

}
```

I am getting jpeg image type everytime. Using signature.js to get image in jpeg format.
Thanks

Comment: first step: stop using `@`. it's the (childish) equivalent of stuffing your fingers in your ears and going "lalalalala can't hear you". You know your code is having problems, yet you're telling php "shut up, I don't care". you're simply assuming that everything will always work perfectly and that failures NEVER occur... good luck with that outlook.

Comment: Where do you have a problem? What effect do you NOT want, and what effect do you EXPECT? IMHO your code prepares a jpeg image, read from a file, for doing anything with it, but I don't see what it does or should do with this image.

Comment: It is creating a black image. That is the problem.

Comment: what PHP version you use? I have similar problem with PHP v5.3.3 (debian 6) and I suspect this is the PHP-distribution (gd.so) issue. It was appear after updates to 5.3.3.1-7+squeeze27 (squeeze28 has this problem too). squeeze26 - doesn't has that. :( `imagecreatefromjpeg()` break script with `warning: bad type specifier while parsing parameters`. Another suggestion - filesystem privileges.

Comment: I am using PHP Version 5.4.43. Can you guide me how to solve this issue?

Comment: @talhamalik22 , unfortunately, I didn't resolve it yet :(

Comment: can you guys take a look at this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35369391/image-from-signature-js-to-fpdf-cannot-load-image
This is the problem I am facing
@MarcB

Comment: @Wizard please look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35369391/image-from-signature-js-to-fpdf-cannot-load-image

Comment: @talhamalik22 , I resolved my local problem. As it turned out I had cli & cgi version 5.3.3.1-7+squeeze28, but I forgot that earlier I have to compile manually fpm version 5.3.3.1-1. Now I have updated php to version 5.3.29-1 from dotdeb.org. All works fine.